# How to access/set inherited properties from a class that uses the shadow DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, inheritance, shadow-dom

I have 2 typescript classes, one extending HTMLElement and one extending that class. Both of these refer to custom HTML elements I'm using throughout my project. I'm having some confusion with the inheritance here.

```
export class NewElement extends HTMLElement { //custom element is new-element
   constructor(){
      super();
      this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
      this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = html; //imported from an external html file, just a div
   }

   public get Val() { return this.val; } 
   public set Val(value) { //setter with callback } 
   private val = "";
 
   public get Name() {return this.name; } 
   public set Name(value) { //setter with callback} 
   private name = "";
 
   ...
}

export class ExtendedElement extends NewElement { //custom element is extended-element
   constructor(//does something get passed in here?) {
      super(//or here?);

      /// ???
   }
}
```

I want to be able to add a series of `<extended-element/>`s to the DOM and set its properties in the attributes like such:
`<extended-element val="OK" name="first"></extended-element>`
access the values of these attributes from within the ExtendedElement class and perform the same operations on that value as I would in the NewElement class. How would I write getters/setters in ExtendedElement, or can I somehow use the same ones from NewElement? Are both getters and setters needed in this case?

Comment: Did you try something and did it not work? Your question should show an example of using `<extended-element>` and what doesn't work. Otherwise, your question is too vague. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Getter and setter that are defined in the parent class will be inherited to the child class. So `public get Val()` defined in `NewElement` will be available to `ExtendedElement`.

I would change the way you use them, though. Currently they only get and set a private value, without any processing between, making it behave the same as just assigning and reading a property value.

Instead use them to get and set the attribute values on the element. This is somewhat similar to a `href` getter and setter behaves on an `<a>` tag, making your custom element behave like a native element would, which in my opinion, would be desired behavior.

I've added a JavaScript implementation of the inheritance and the usage of getters and setters.

```js
class NewElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = '';
  }

  get name() {
    return this.getAttribute('name');
  }

  set name(value) {
    this.setAttribute('name', value);
  }

  get val() {
    return this.getAttribute('val');
  }

  set val(value) {
    this.setAttribute('val', value);
  }
}

class ExtendedElement extends NewElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  
  /**
   * This is a lifecycle hook and will be called
   * whenever the custom element is added to the page, 
   * like when loading the page.
   * @link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements#using_the_lifecycle_callbacks
   */
  connectedCallback() {
    console.log(this.name, this.val);
  }
}

customElements.define('extended-element', ExtendedElement);
```

```html
<extended-element val="OK" name="first"></extended-element>
```